# EnumSet doesn't think my enum is an enum

Tags: java, enums

Inside my production code, I am constructing a EnumSet inside a constructor of an enum, but it fails to detect that my class is an actual enum. This bug is breaking my real production code

I made up the following class for testing purposes, but even with this small example it keeps failing to recognise the enum. How can I mark my class as an enum in the way EnumSet knows it is an enum?

Simple source code:

```
package test;
import java.util.*; // Set, EnumSet, Arrays
public enum Alphabet {
    A, 
    B(A), 
    C(A, B), 
    D(A, B, C),
    // You get the point
    ;
    Set<Alphabet> prevLetters;

    Alphabet() {
        prevLetters = EnumSet.noneOf(Alphabet.class); // <- EnumSet here
    }

    Alphabet(Alphabet... prev) {
        this();
        prevLetters.addAll(Arrays.asList(prev));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Alphabet.values()));
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class test.Alphabet not an enum
    at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:112)
    at test.Alphabet.<init>(Test.java:13)
    at test.Alphabet.<clinit>(Test.java:4)
```

Comment: @Joe While the question is a dublicate (That I missed while searching), I must state that the other question isn't really that good written and requires a lot of reading to see my problem in it, this question is written more clearly

Comment: Just use the ordinal: `public List<Alphabet> previous() {
        List<Alphabet> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Alphabet.values())
                          .subList(0,
                                   this.ordinal()));
        return list;
    }`

Comment: The problem is that you can't form an `EnumSet` from an `enum` that hasn't been fully initialized.  The Alphabet constructor is invoked at a time when all of the enum instances have not been constructed.  If there were no exception, the program would be allowed to observe enum constants in an inconsistent state.  In this case, the Exception is preventing your application from having bugs.  An enum constructor should not perform initializations that depend on the state of other constants in the same enum.

Comment: I edited your note about duplicates because it's not really needed since that is actually the point of duplicates. You can see on the [help center here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) that they're intentionally to allow searches to find the one useful answer easier.